# HTTP request in separate function[node.js/expressjs]

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

By using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module I have something like this and it works perfectly.
But when i try to restructure the code or make it reusable, it finish executing before it finished the HTTP requests. Nodejs do lots of things in asynchronous way so finding a solution to this is bit hard to me.

### What I have up to now.

```
  var async = require('async'),
  http = require('http');

  exports.unitedStates = function(req, res) {

    var texas = {
      //GET method data here / ex: host, path, headers....
    };

    var washington = {
      //GET method data here / ex: host, path, headers....
    };


    async.parallel({
        getSource: function(callback) {
          http.request(texas, function(respond) {
            //Http request
          }).end();
        },
        getScreen: function(callback) {
          http.request(washington, function(respond) {
            //Http request
          }).end();
        }
      },
      function(err, results) {
        //Return the results

        /* REPLY TO THE REQUEST */
        res.send( /* data here */ );
      });

}
```

is there a perfect way to make this piece of code to **reusable**?

### Example

```
exports.unitedStates = function(req, res) {
  var tokyo = japan();

  //send the result to front end
  res.send(tokyo);
}

function japan(){
  //async calls comes here and return the value...
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning value from function, pass a callback.

```
exports.unitedStates = function (req, res) {

   // pass callback here
   japan(function (value) {
       res.send(value);  
   });
} 

function japan(cb) {
   //async call here

   cb(result);
}
```

Comment: just what I needed. Worked perfectly :D